# What table information do I need to be able to connect my database externally?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to connect my moodle site to my magento shopping cart. The enrolment plug in, in moodle is asking for my stores database info: 
host, Database Name,  DB User & password which I have, but I also need

Name of the table in the database - I assume this is the customer stored data so I have entered mag_customer_entity

Username field 
Password field - Which I can not find in php my admin
Password format

Does anybody know where I can find this information? I thought that using the table "mag_customer_entity" would be obvious but there is no username and password field available here, yet there is the customers email address and id number etc.

Any help with this I will be forever greatful! thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2):

Magento does not use usernames. You log in using your e-mail address. So I guess the username is the e-mail field in the `customer_entity` table.
The passwords are stored in the table `customer_entity_varchar` because the customer entity in Magento is an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) entity. `Password` is a varchar attribute for the customer entity and it's values are kept in the `customer_entity_varchar` table.

To find the password hash associated to a customer you need this query.
Let's say the customer id is `10`.  Add the table prefix if you have one.

```
SELECT 
    `value` 
FROM 
    `customer_entity_varchar` 
WHERE 
    `entity_id` = 10 AND
    `attribute_id` = (SELECT 
                         `e`.`attribute_id` 
                      FROM 
                         `eav_attribute` e
                      LEFT JOIN
                          `eav_entity_type` et 
                          ON `e`.`entity_type_id` = `et`.`entity_type_id`
                      WHERE 
                          `e`.`attribute_code` = 'password_hash' AND
                          `et`.`entity_type_code` = 'customer'
                     )
```

Comment: Although it's not been updated for a few versions you might want to have a look [here](http://www.magereverse.com/) to more easily find the relationship between EAV tables in the database.